# Identification of Peaks from a Line Graph

Tags: python, algorithm, image, graph, signals

[I have added a link to the data set here.](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21APs492EP1FWj2qQ&cid=D2800E3985FF0B72&id=D2800E3985FF0B72%21491&parId=root&o=OneUp)The first script produces a line graph using signal output data. My next step was to identify the peaks present on the line graph. The second script has an algorithm to identify all the peaks present on the line graph. However it is too sensitive. It classifies even the slightest bumps on the graph as a peak. I do not want this. I only wish to identify the conspicous(large) bumps as peaks. How do I modify the second script to do this?[Line Graph][2]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X, Y = [], []
X = np.zeros((10, 4096))
Y = np.zeros((10, 4096))

n=0
m=0
for line in open('data_set2.txt', 'r'):
  values = [float(s) for s in line.split()]
  X[n,0] = values[0]-1566518691968
  for m in range(4096):
      Y[n,m]=values[m+1]

  n=n+1
plt.plot(Y[1,0:4095])
plt.show()



b = (X[1:]-X[:-1])[:-1]
c = (X[:-1]-X[1:])[1:]
minima = np.where(np.bitwise_and(b<0, c<0))[0]+1
maxima = np.where(np.bitwise_and(b>0, c>0))[0]+1
all_peaks = np.where((b*c)>0)[0]+1
del b,c

print(minima)
print(maxima)
print(all_peaks)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the sample of our dataset - `data_set2.txt` .

Comment: I have edited the question and provided a link to the data set. Also the "X" used in the second script represent the shape of the array, which in my case is 4096.

Answer (score 0):

I wish you had attached the data set so I can try my solution before I post it here. What I think you're doing is looking for all the points that are higher than the point before and point after them, which is why you're ending up with too many points. What your code should look for tho is a number of the highest peaks. It does not matter if the point is a peak, and the peak's height itself does not matter either, what matters is the "uniqueness" of the peak, or how much it is higher than the average point. Imagine removing the highest three peaks in your example and zooming in, you will find a new number of peaks that look much higher than the rest; and so on.
The tricky thing for you is to find the number of those peaks which depends on how sensitive you want your code to be.

Comment: Thank you fo the suggestion, I have provided a link to the data set for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are some packages for identifying peaks. scypi provides `scipy.signal.find_peaks`function (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html). There are also peak identification for matlab, octave and others.
All of them require some quantitative criteria for peak identification. None will work with just "conspicous(large) bumps".

UPD. So, if you want to write the code yourself, you have choose some filtering function. There may be some pretty obvious:

1. Peaks that have value greater than `x`;
2. Peaks that are greater than `x%` of maximum peak's value;
3. `x` largest peaks (where `x` < total numbers of peaks.

Varying parameter x you can come to solution that satisfies your criteria of "conspicous(large) bumps".

P. S. There might be other filtering functions, but it looks that in your case width and form of peak do not matter.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm aware of different peak finding libraries, but my task is to modify my own script to reduce its sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of the algorithms suggested by someone here; if I were you I'd check them out because their way should be more efficient. However, if you want to be lazy, here is a solution:
First I gather all the peaks (the same peaks you get):

```
x_range = range(4096)
peaks = []
for line in open('data_set2.txt', 'r'):
    values = [float(s) for s in line.split()]
    X[n, 0] = values[0] - 1566518691968
    for m in range(4096):
        Y[n, m] = values[m + 1]

        # only work with the plotted row starting from the third value
        if n != 1 or m in (0, 1):
            continue
        
        # if a point is higher than the point before and point after 
        if Y[n, m - 2] < Y[n, m - 1] > Y[n, m]:
            peaks.append((x_range[m-1], Y[n, m - 1]))
    n = n + 1

plt.plot(Y[1, 0:4095])
plt.show()
```

Then I loop through each 100 points (assuming no two peaks can occur in 100 point-range, otherwise one of them will be discarded) and find the maximum. If the segment maximum is some percentage of the absolute maximum, it is included.

```
max_ = max(peaks, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]

# If the graph does not have peaks
if max_ < np.mean(Y) * 10:       # Tweak point 1
    print("No peaks")
    sys.exit()

highest = []
sensitivity = 0.2        # Tweak point 2
for i in range(0, len(peaks), 100):
    try:
        segment = peaks[i: i + 100]
    except IndexError:
        segment = peaks[i:]
    finally:
        segment_max = max(segment, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
        if segment_max >= max_ * sensitivity:
            highest.append(segment_max)

print(highest)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The explaination was very helpful.

Comment: What did you import to use peaks.append and where is it defined?

Comment: Oh sorry about that, peaks is just an empty list defined before the first line. Then I fill it up in peaks.append. Also, x_range is defined before as:
x_range = range(4096)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I really appreciate it.